# java.exe process always running on solr ports on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, jetty

On starting solr with the command `bin\solr.cmd start` it shows the normal starting statement:

```
C:\solr-8.11.2>bin\solr.cmd start
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: 
JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory.
```

- Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
- Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching but I could not access solr on the admin, when I used the command `bin\solr.cmd status` it shows:

  ```
  Found Solr process 7992 running on port 8983
  {
  "solr_home":"C:\\solr-8.11.2\\server\\solr",
  "version":"8.11.2 17dee71932c683e345508113523e764c3e4c80fa - mdrob - 2022-06-13 11:27:54",
  "startTime":"2023-06-24T16:13:12.602Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 7 minutes, 43 seconds",
  "memory":"55.5 MB (%10.8) of 512 MB"}
  ```
- When I changed the port number using the `bin\solr.cmd start -p 8984` command and check the status again, it still shows that another process is still running on port 8984.
- When I checked with currport it shows:

  ```
  java.exe  7992    TCP 8983        0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0     
  Listening C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe Java(TM)
  Platform SE 8 Java(TM) Platform SE binary 8.0.2020.8  Oracle Corporation  24/06/2023 17:13:12 DESKTOP-GJBI99T\DELL    
  A 24/06/2023 17:26:53 24/06/2023 17:13:18
  ```
- It shows that `jva.exe` process is listening on `port 8983` routed to an IP address 0.0.0.0. The same thing with port 8984
- When I changed the port number with `-p`, I was expecting the solr app to run on the new port number but I got the same response. I uninstalled the solr app and reinstalled it, but the same thing happened.

Comment: You know that Solr is written in Java and the Java process you see is being used by Solr, right? So what is it you hope to gain by getting then to run on different ports? This smells strongly of an [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info) -- you would do well to state the real purpose of your question instead of addressing issues that are unlikely to go anywhere.

Comment: My question is that, I can't start solr instant on the default port 8983 because a java exe process is always running on it with ip address 0.0.0.0. if I change the port to 8984 for example using -p  another java.exe is running on port 8984 on so on continuously.with the same ip address 0.0.0.0. help me please. I'm stuck

Comment: It's not that, I want the java.exe process not to run .the issues is that, there are always many instances of the java.exe  process running on the IP address 127.0.0.01 and two of them are always running on door default port or any port assigned to solr with -p on a remote address of 0.0.0.0 and I can never start solr on my machine!?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not already running a Solr instance that automagically starts up on boot or that you've started previously?  The output given seems to indicate that you've already started Solr and that it runs on port 8983 as well (the `java.exe` process _is_ Solr).

Comment: When `solr status` returns "Found Solr process 7992 running on port 8983 " ... what happens if point your browser to http://localhost:8983/ ? You should see the Solr home page.

Comment: This non programming question seems better suited for the [serverfault.com community](https://serverfault.com/) (another more focused stackexchange website)

Comment: Sorry guys, it was all my fault. Matsunah was right, I was running two solr instances at the same time..Thanks for your concern.